# Conditional dropdown not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

This is related to `HTML` and `JavaScript`. I'm a newbie in `HTML` and `JavaScript`.
I have four `DropDowns`. The first two are dependent on each other. The next two are dependent on each other. The first two `DropDowns` work perfectly.
For e.g. if the option No school is selected, the second `DropDown` populates values as expected.

The same does not happen for the next two `DropDowns`. If **No** is chosen in the third `DropDown`, the fourth `DropDown` should populate a list.
This does not happen.
Please run the code to understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
David

The code is:

```js
function dynamic_sch(listindex)
            {
                 document.getElementById("subcategory").length = 0;
                switch (listindex)
                {
                    case "No_sch_att" :
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select reason","");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Did not know what to do","Did not know what to do");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Unable to provide escort","Unable to provide escort");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Unable to adjust in school setting","Unable to adjust in school setting");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Cant travel long distance","Cant travel long distance");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Cant afford travel","Cant travel long distance");
                        break;

                    case "Spl_sch" :
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select reason","");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Only option available","Only option available");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Could not adjust in mainstream school","Could not adjust in mainstream school");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Denied admission in mainstream school","Denied admission in mainstream school");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Parents preferred choice","Parents preferred choice");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Non availability of escort/transport","Non availability of escort/transport");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Not happy with progress quality in school","Not happy with progress quality in school");
                        break;
                    case  "home_edn" :
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select reason","");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Preferred choice","Preferred choice");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Did not know what to do","Did not know what to do");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Unable to provide escort","Unable to provide escort");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Unable to adjust in school setting","Unable to adjust in school setting");
                        document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Cant travel long distance","Cant travel long distance");
                        break;
                      }
                return true;
                
                
            }


   function dynamic_yn(listindex)
            {
                document.getElementById("sub_category").length = 0;
                switch (listindex)
                {
                    case "no_rec" :
                        document.getElementById("sub_category").options[0]=new Option("Please select reason","");
                        document.getElementById("sub_category").options[1]=new Option("Did not know what to do","Did not know what to do");
                        document.getElementById("sub_category").options[2]=new Option("Unable to provide escort","Unable to provide escort");
                        document.getElementById("sub_category").options[3]=new Option("Unable to adjust in school setting","Unable to adjust in school setting");
                        document.getElementById("sub_category").options[4]=new Option("Cant travel long distance","Cant travel long distance");
                        document.getElementById("sub_category").options[5]=new Option("Cant afford travel","Cant travel long distance");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
                
                
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

 <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">
        <label>School attended</label>
            <select name="category" style="max-width:70%" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="JavaScriptt: dynamic_sch(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <option value="">Select School attended</option>
                <option value="No_sch_att">No school attended</option>
                <option value="Incl_mainst">Inclusive Mainstream</option>
                <option value="Spl_sch">Special School</option>
                <option value="Int_spl_nrml">Integrated Spl+Normal</option>
                <option value="home_edn">Home Education</option>
                <option value="Opn_sch">Open Schooling</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
             <div class="category_div" id="category_div">
                 <label>Reason Why ?</label>
                 <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" style="max-width:100%"><option value="">Please select reason         </option></select>
            <noscript>
                <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" 
                    <option value="">Please select reason</option>
                </select>
            </noscript>
        </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div class="category" id="category">
        <label>Access to play</label>
            <select name="category" style="max-width:70%" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="JavaScriptt: dynamic_yn(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <option value="">Select Choice</option>
                <option value="Yes_rec">Yes</option>
                <option value="no_rec">No</option>
                
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <div class="sub_category" id="sub_category">
             <div class="category" id="category">
                 <label>Reason Why ?</label>
                 <select name="sub_category" id="sub_category" style="max-width:100%"><option value="">Please select reason         </option></select>
            <noscript>
                <select name="sub_category" id="sub_category"> 
                    <option value="">Please select reason</option>
                </select>
            </noscript>
        </div>
 </div>
 </div>


 

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked your code , isssue is coming becuase for your last dropdown you have two elements having same id, hence the script is not updating the options

first one

```
<div class="sub_category" id="sub_category">
```

second one

```
<select name="sub_category" id="sub_category"
```

change the id for div and it should work

Answer (score 0):

In `HTML` file `id` should be unique. In your code snippet you have multiple elements with same `id`. For example,

```
<div class="category" id="category">
    <label>Access to play</label>
    <select name="category" style="max-width:70%" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="JavaScriptt: dynamic_yn(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="Yes_rec">Yes</option>
        <option value="no_rec">No</option>       
    </select>
</div>
```

In above code you have `category` as `id` to `div` and `select`. Change the `id` of `div`,

```
<div class="category" id="category_div">
```

Also this,

```
<div class="sub_category" id="sub_category">
    <div class="category" id="category"> //This id should be removed
       <label>Reason Why ?</label>
       <select name="sub_category" id="sub_category" style="max-width:100%">
            <option value="">Please select reason </option>
       </select>
       <noscript>
         <select name="sub_category" id="sub_category">
             <option value="">Please select reason</option>
         </select>
       </noscript>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above code you have `sub_category` as `id` to `div` and `select`. Also you need to remove `id="category"` wchich is not necessory.  Change the `id` of `div`,

```
<div class="sub_category" id="sub_category_div">
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/hojuyahixu/edit?html,js,output)

**Note:** You have added 2 select with same `id` in last block. If not needed you can remove one.